# How to change some specific fields of a structure without using for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, structure, field

Lets suppose, we have a structure and want to change the same field in some desired indexes without using costly for loops.
Can anyone suggest a solution to do it?

An example:

Lets suppose we have a structure which is called student, and we want to change the field 'average' for (student no#125, no#231, no#245, no#256 and so on) when it is necessary. Then as i know we should write it as below:

```
should2change = [125, 231, 245, 256, ....];

for i = 1:numel(should2change)

   student(should2change(i,1)).average = student(should2change(i,1)).average + 1;

end
```

is there a straightforward way to avoid using this kind of costly for loops while doing exactly the same task?

Comment: Have you profiled your actual problem? The loop as presented takes milliseconds to run.

Comment: Actually i am not sure that 'for loops' are my actual problem or not, but im sure that my code has to run the same loops times after times and most times my code runs very slowly, while i have a 16 Gb of ram on my laptop and my CPU is core i7 !

Comment: Run your function under [the profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html). What you're doing smells like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's not a very good way to get around a for loop -- if you don't know what elements you'll access ahead of time. However, if you really want to, you can do what is called loop unrolling, where you write the instruction out x number of times instead of doing a for loop x times. So, for instance, if you know that should2change (s2c here) will *always* have 5 items, you can do:

```
student(s2c(1,1).average = s2c(1,1).avg+1
student(s2c(2,1).average = s2c(2,1).avg+1
student(s2c(3,1).average = s2c(3,1).avg+1
student(s2c(4,1).average = s2c(4,1).avg+1
student(s2c(5,1).average = s2c(5,1).avg+1
```

Perhaps this could be parallelized, but unless it really will boost performance, I wouldn't worry.

I don't think that's what you're going for though, in which case, a for loop is probably best. But for loops aren't too costly in matlab. The only time you really have to start worrying about it is if you start nesting for loops (always a bad idea.)

Comment: I think the solution you introduced is good, but i dont know how many indexes should change each time my recursive program wants to do the same task.

Comment: OK then a for loop is your best bet, because you can change the number of iterations during runtime.  If you know that it's going to be an even number of changes, you can at least do 2 changes at once, but other than that, yeah... for loops, that's what they're for.